# Usage of spark._jsparkSession.catalog().tableExists() in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, delta-lake, hive-metastore

Is it advisable to use spark._jsparkSession.catalog().tableExists() to check the table exists in spark for databricks delta-table in pyspark.

The question arises because _jsparkSession is a internal attribute in pyspark? and user should not access?

Answer (score 2):

it could be used because there is no parity between Scala & Python APIs.  But you can use something like this to check if the table exists:

```py
def table_exists(table: str, database: str = "default") -> bool:
  tbl = spark.sql(f"show tables in `{database}`") \
    .filter(f"tableName = '{table}'")
  return tbl.count() > 0
```